# How to normalize interaction terms?

Tags: classification, interaction

I'm training a classifier for a supervised classification problem. Some of my features interact, how should I normalize these interaction terms?

For example, if x1 and x2 interact, the interaction term is x1*x2. Should the values of x1*x2 be computed before x1 and x2 are normalized, and then normalized. Or should x1*x2 be computed from normalized values of x1 and x2?